# How to pass URL parameters across all pages/internal links in a site with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, url

I have a site with two pages, `index.html` and `page2.html`:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Homepage</title>    
    <style type="text/css">
      #holder {margin: 20px auto; max-width: 900px;}      
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="holder">
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="/page2.html">Internal Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.apple.com/" target="_blank">App Store</a> 
   </li>
      </ul>
      <h2 id="useApp">Is the user using our app?</h2>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

page2.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Page 2</title>    
    <style type="text/css">
      #holder {margin: 20px auto; max-width: 900px;}      
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="holder">
      <h1>Internal Page</h1>
      <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="/index.html">Homepage</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.apple.com/" target="_blank">App Store</a> 
       </li>
      </ul>
      <h2 id="useApp">Is the user using our app?</h2>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When the user lands on index.html by clicking a Google ad, in order to enable tracking the ad appends the following parameters to the end of the URL:

`?utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=summer19`

A problem that arises is when a user navigates to another page within the site, these URL parameters are lost.  I would like to write some Javascript that passes the URL parameters across the user's journey on the site when they click on internal links. In the case of external links, it MUST NOT include these parameters.  How can I implement this most effectively?

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem here is what is an internal link? If you're 100% certain that internal links will always be in relative form (i.e. `/index.html` instead of `http://www.example.com/index.html`), then you could check for the starting characters. But you need to make that assumption.

Comment: Maybe instead of attaching the params to every link you may store it within the [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) and access it when you need it.

Answer (score 6):

Use `querySelectorAll` to find all elements with a `href` attribute, and attach the search string from `URL(window.location).search`:

```
var queryString = new URL(window.location).search;
document.querySelectorAll("[href]").forEach(link => {
    var current = link.href;
    link.href = current + queryString;
});
```

## EDIT

Here is how to make the above apply only to internal links (I classify *internal links* as those that either start with a `/` or `.` (relative links), or start with `http` and include `window.location.hostname` (absolute links):

```
var queryString = new URL(window.location).search;
document.querySelectorAll("[href]").forEach(link => {
            if (link.href.startsWith("/") || link.href.startsWith(".") || (link.href.startsWith("http") && link.href.include(window.location.hostname)) {
                    var current = link.href;
                    link.href = current + queryString;
                }
            });
```

Comment: I think this does not distinguish between internal links and external links, or am I missing something?

Comment: @JackBashford could you provide a code sample that does this only for internal links?

Comment: @ChatterOne I have fixed it now.

Comment: @EricR. Edited my answer, does it work for you now?

Comment: @JackBashford Another, possibly safer, way but which requires more code and a `try/catch` is to compare `window.location.hostname` with `new URL(link).hostname` (the try/catch is there because of the invalid parameter in case of relative URLs).

Comment: This will also mess up links that had a query string already.

Comment: I think you're missing a `)` at the end of your `if`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method to check internal or external link:

```
var isExternal = function(url) {
    return !(location.href.replace("http://", "").replace("https://", "").split("/")[0] === url.replace("http://", "").replace("https://", "").split("/")[0]);   
}
```

This way we can get the parameter string from the URL:

```
var params = new URL(window.location).search;
```

Finally loop through all the page links and filter the internal links. Then append the parameter string to each internal links:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[href]").forEach(li => {
    var current = li.href;
    if(isExternal(current)){
        li.href = current + params;
    }    
});
```